# Does a website I visit know which Chrome extensions I have installed?

Tags: google-chrome, internet, chromium

I’m just curious to know how much a site can find out about my computer setup. Can they see the chrome extensions I use? I know they know my OS, screen size, IP location and a few other ones, but what about browser extensions. Do they know I use AdBlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are ways for a website to see what extensions are being used. I use adblock and sometimes i will see: I see you are using addblock, please disable for full site functionality. for more information on the adblock please vist: stackoverflow because it says how.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869154/how-to-detect-adblock-on-my-website